# Show that $n \log n $ is $\mathcal{O}(\log n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found a proof that proceeds as follows:

Notice that $\log(n^n)$ is at most a constant times $\log(n!)$, which in turn is equivalent to the statement that $n^n$ is at most a constant power of $n!$. We will show that in fact $n^n \lt (n!)^2 $ for all $n>1$. To do this, let us write $(n!)^2$ as $(n·1)·((n - 1) ·2)-((n-2)·3)\textit{...}(2·(n-1))·(1·n)$. Now clearly each product pair $(i+1)·(n-i)$ is at least as big as $n$ (indeed, the ones near the middle are significantly bigger than $n$). Therefore the entire
product is at least as big as $n^n$, as desired.

I think it was assumed that the following is true:
$$n^n < n! \lt (n!)^2 $$

**Questions**:

1. Why it was wrote $(n!)^2$ as $(n·1)·((n - 1) ·2)-((n-2)·3)\textit{...}(2·(n-1))·(1·n)$?
2. Why $(i+1)·(n-i)$ is at least as big as $n$, or in other words $(i+1)·(n-i) \ge n$?

Comment: $n^n$ is usually an upper bound on $n!$...

Comment: @DonThousand. Thank you The question asks to show that $n \log n $ is $\mathcal{O}(\log n!)$, which is equivalent to $\log n^n $ is $\mathcal{O}(\log n!)$

Comment: See Stirling approximation of $n!$.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you. I know that but the question here assumes the opposite!